# How to create a component hierarchy with boilerplatejs?

Tags: javascript, boilerplatejs

In the [boilerplatejs](http://boilerplatejs.org) zip, there is a sample component (salesDashBoard) with two sub-components (chartViewPanel and treeViewPanel)
The parent component defines a view.html with two divs with ids #tree and #chart, but the sub components are appended to this view instead of being rendered in these two divs.

Is there a way (maybe with a DomController ?) to attach subcomponents to specific DOM elements instead of just appending them ? That would be very useful, ideally I would love to have a hierarchy of Dom / Url controllers: the parents would intercept events and then route them to children, until a child routes an event (for a particular set of url / dom events) to a simple component with a MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI's rendering outside the defined div's was actually a bug and is [fixed](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/src/modules/sampleModule2/salesDashboard/component.js) now.

Yes, you can attach sub view templates to specific DOM elements. The `Boiler.ViewTemplate` accepts a parent parameter and you have to pass the DOM element which it needs to be rendered in.

As for the second part of your question, what you need is a hierarchy of `contexts`. You can keep the controller hierarchy on UI components. Just convert all your UI components to be sub modules as well. Meaning each of your UI component will have a `module.js` file and be child of the parent module. For example take a look at `application.js` to see how it loads its child modules with `Base.Context.loacChildContexts()` method.

You can read more about this concept under the "Product Modules" section on [BoilerplateJS website](http://boilerplatejs.org/)